# Symmetric group and cyclic permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that if $n$ is at least $4$, every element of $S_n$ can be written as a product of two permutations, each of which has order $2$. I have no idea to prove the above statement. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a proof here starting on the third page: http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/math109/hw3.pdf. It  starts by showing how to write a cycle as a product of two permutations of order 2. You can try reading that part and see if you can continue the rest of the proof on your own.